# widget.setLayout(layout) vs layout = QLayout(widget)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Are

```
widget = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
```

and

```
widget = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
widget.setLayout(layout)
```

the same things?

They look like the same. But may be I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, they are doing the same thing: `layout` will become the layout manager of `widget` in case there is no existing layout manager for `widget`.